# Java Spring MVC: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I've problems setting up Spring MVC... I've this project structure

```
-SpringTest<br />
   -Java Resources
      -src
         -org.basic.controller
             FormController.java
.
.
.
.
-WebContent
   +META-INF
   -WEB-INF
       dispatcher-servlet.xml
       +lib
       -views
           form.jsp
       web.xml
```

And these are the code pages:

**web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

  <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">



    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**FormController.java**

```
package org.basic.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/form.html")
public class FormController {


}
```

But when, after a deploy with jboss, I try to access "/SpringTest/form.htm" it gives back this error:

**WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringTest/form.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'**

Comment: I downloaded an example which uses to put classes inside the web-inf folder... and it works... could it be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are not scanning the controller.
Where is your context:component scan?
Try adding it.

Also,why is your controller empty?Is it that you have not pasted code just to make it look clear in the Question or you haven't written anything in the Class? –

Comment: Added component scan and annotation-driven but still get 404 :(

Comment: @AndreaDorigo Please update the Question with the changes also when you do some changes .

Comment: @AndreaDorigo why is your controller empty?is it that you have not pasted code just to make it look clear in the Question or you haven't written anything in the Class?

Comment: I DID IT!!!! After your various suggestions it worked; I just had to turn off and then on the jboss server to make the updates effective... I don't know why often the jboss eclipse plugin costrain me to turn it off and on to see the changes... as If I've the "auto-build" propery checked...

Comment: @AndreaDorigo cool then.please accept my answer and also let me know if you made any changes in the controller class.check my previous comment.If so then I will update that in my answer also.

Comment: I put this code inside it
<code>
@RequestMapping(value="/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(ModelMap map) {
        map.addAttribute("hello", "Hello Spring!!");
        return "register";
    }
</code>

Answer (score 5):

```
@RequestMapping("/form.html")
```

vs

```
/SpringTest/form.htm
```

You have an extra `l` in your `@RequestMapping` url.

Don't forget to `component-scan` the package your controller is in.

Comment: I've tried but I got the same error :(
Is anything wrong about the logic?